# margin-right on last child isn't working in Safari

Tags: html, css, sass, safari, margin

I have a bunch of cards in a sideways-scrolling container.

The first card gets a margin on its left, and the last card on its right.

```scss
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  &:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
  &:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
}
```

This works fine on Chrome, but the last card doesn't get a margin in Safari.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Check out [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-blackwell-tmtsz2?file=/src/styles.scss:356-382) in Safari, and notice that there's no margin to the right of the last card.

**Sidenote:** Yes, I know that loads of people have asked this before, but I didn't find any answers that solved the problem, and most of those questions failed to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If you don't find a solution try using last-child instead

Comment: @BernardBorg It's not about that. If you inspect the element you'll see that the margin is applied to the element. It just doesn't render that way.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac so I'm trying to help blind here

Comment: Set `padding-left and padding-right` to 18px on your .cards element and remove the margins. See if that works.

Comment: @BernardBorg That would make the cards not scroll all the way to the edges of the screen.

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately, I can't help you further than this